# How to convert Year and Day of Year to Date?

Tags: python, date, julian-date

I have a year value and a day of year and would like to convert to a date (day/month/year).

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days - 1)
```

Comment: How is this simpler than SilentGhost's answer?

Comment: @GreenMatt: It doesn't involve putting the numbers into a string and then parsing that string.

Comment: This was really meant for Mino; I guess I should have put "@Mino" in the comment, sorry.  It's true that this method does not require converting numbers to a string; however, in my experience you're at least equally likely to be starting with a string.  More to the point, two calls and an arithematic operation are more complicated than a single call IMO.  (Granted, the number of calls will depend on any conversions needed.)

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it also works for decimal days. I submitted an edit to add that.

Answer (score 34):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2010 120', '%Y %j')
datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 30, 0, 0)
>>> _.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
'30/04/2010'
```

Answer (score 8):

The [`toordinal()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.toordinal) and [`fromordinal()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromordinal) functions of the `date` class  could be used:

```
from datetime import date
date.fromordinal(date(year, 1, 1).toordinal() + days - 1)
```

Answer (score 6):

since it is pretty common these days, a `pandas` option, using `pd.to_datetime` with specified unit and origin:

```
import pandas as pd

day, year = 21, 2021

print(pd.to_datetime(day-1, unit='D', origin=str(year)))
# 2021-01-21 00:00:00
```

Comment: When day and year are already in a dataframe, then... `df['md'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'], format='%j').dt.strftime('%m-%d')`. And `df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'].astype(str) + '-' + df.md)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the mx.DateTime module to get the date is similar to what has been proposed above using `datetime` and `timedelta`. Namely:

```
import mx.DateTime as dt 
date = dt.DateTime(yyyy,mm,dd) + dt.DateTimeDeltaFromDays(doy-1)
```

So, given that you know the year (say, 2020) and the doy (day of the year, say 234), then:

```
date = dt.DateTime(2020,1,1) + dt.DateTimeFromDays(233)
```

which returns

```
2020-08-21 00:00:00.00
```

The advantage of the mx.DateTime library is that has many useful features. As per description in its [homepage](https://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/):

- Parses date/time string values in an almost seamless way.
- Provides conversion routines to and from many different alternative date/time
  storage formats.
- Includes an easy-to-use C API which makes
  integration a breeze.
- Fast, memory efficient, accurate.
- Georgian and Julian calendar support.
- Vast range of valid dates (including B.C. dates).
- Stable, robust and portable (mxDateTime has been around for almost 15 years
  now).
- Fully interoperates with Python's time and datetime modules.

Comment: what is the `mx` module? what does this add to a simple solution with datetime and timedelta?

Comment: In this case not much. mx.DateTime has many more methods that can be used when needed.

Comment: ok maybe you could add a link to the docs of the module, source code repo etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>>import datetime
>>>year = int(input())
>>>month = int(input())
>>>day = int(input())
data = datetime.datetime(year,month,day)
daynew = data.toordinal()
yearstart = datetime.datetime(year,1,1)
day_yearstart = yearstart.toordinal()
print ((daynew-day_yearstart)+1)
```

Comment: This seems to do the exact opposite of what the question asks