# calculate month out of number of days in year

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python Question: Year and Day of Year to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427555/python-question-year-and-day-of-year-to-date)

Is there a method in Python to figure out which month a certain day of the year is in, e.g. today is day 299 (October 26th). I would like to figure out, that day 299 is in month 10 (to compile the string to set the Linux system time). 
How can I do this?

Comment: Also, October 26th is day 300 this year, not day 299.  Leap year, you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print (datetime.datetime(2012,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(days=299)).month
```

Here's a little more usable version that returns both the month and day:

```
def get_month_day(year, day, one_based=False):
    if one_based:  # if Jan 1st is 1 instead of 0
        day -= 1
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days=day)
    return dt.month, dt.day

>>> get_month_day(2012, 299)
(10, 26)
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, also, how do I find out which day of the month it actually is?

Comment: Got it: print (datetime.datetime(2012,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(days=299)).day

Answer (score 1):

I know of no such method, but you can do it like this:

```
print datetime.datetime.strptime('2012 299', '%Y %j').month
```

The above prints `10`