# python pandas time series select day of year

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe

I want to select data from a dataframe for a particular day of the year.  Here is what I have so far as a minimal example.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime 
from datetime import timedelta
import numpy.random as npr 
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/1990', periods=365*10, freq='D')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(npr.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
print df1
```

That generates:

```
                   0
1990-01-01 -0.032601
1990-01-02 -0.496401
1990-01-03  0.444490
```

etc.
Now I make a list of dates that I want to extract.  I have used this before in pandas, but I suspect this is not the best way to get values for a particular date.  Anyway,

```
td = timedelta(days=31)
dr = pd.date_range(datetime(1990,12,31)+td,datetime(2000,12,31),
                    freq=pd.DateOffset(months=12, days=0))
print dr
```

This, of course, generates:

```
DatetimeIndex(['1991-01-31', '1992-01-31', '1993-01-31', '1994-01-31',
               '1995-01-31', '1996-01-31', '1997-01-31', '1998-01-31',
               '1999-01-31', '2000-01-31'],
dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset: kwds={'months': 12, 'days': 0}>', tz=None)
```

When I try to slice the dataframe by the list of dates, I generate an error:

```
monthly_df1 = df1[dr]
```

Output:

```
KeyError: "['1991-01-30T16:00:00.000000000-0800' '1992-01-30T16:00:00.000000000-0800'\n 
'1993-01-30T16:00:00.000000000-0800' '1994-01-30T16:00:00.000000000-0800'\n 
'1995-01-30T16:00:00.000000000-0800' '1996-01-30T16:00:00.000000000-0800'\n 
'1997-01-30T16:00:00.000000000-0800' '1998-01-30T16:00:00.000000000-0800'\n 
'1999-01-30T16:00:00.000000000-0800' '2000-01-30T16:00:00.000000000-0800'] 
not in index"
```

I think that I have two fundamental problems here: (1) there is a better way to extract yearly data for a particular date; and (2) the time series in the dataframe and date_range list are different.  I would appreciate information on both problems.  Thanks, community.

Comment: I am planning to manipulate a DataFrame

Comment: Doesn't `df1[(df1.index.month==1) & (df1.index.day==31)]` work for you in this case?

Comment: I think that a mask would work, but I would like to be able to adjust by day of year (an integer 1 through 365 or 366).  That allows me to use it inside an optimization routine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `.ix` to filter `dr` dates from `df1`

```
In [107]: df1.ix[dr]
Out[107]:
                   0
1991-01-31 -1.239096
1992-01-31  0.153730
1993-01-31 -0.685778
1994-01-31  0.132170
1995-01-31  0.154965
1996-01-31  1.800437
1997-01-31  2.725209
1998-01-31 -0.084751
1999-01-31  1.604511
2000-01-31       NaN
```

Even `df1.loc[dr]` works.

---

Also, for this case, you can just pass these conditions to extract the dates

```
In [108]: df1[(df1.index.month==1) & (df1.index.day==31)]
Out[108]:
                   0
1990-01-31 -0.362652
1991-01-31 -1.239096
1992-01-31  0.153730
1993-01-31 -0.685778
1994-01-31  0.132170
1995-01-31  0.154965
1996-01-31  1.800437
1997-01-31  2.725209
1998-01-31 -0.084751
1999-01-31  1.604511
```

Comment: Both of these work for my original post. For some reason, only the second works for the problem in my real code (though not for an arbitrary day of year).  Perhaps I need to write a little function to generate the mask parameters for an arbitrary day of year.

Comment: Thanks @JohnGalt.  This does work, and it is easy enough to create a mask with something like 
     datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days - 1)
(see [post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427555/python-question-year-and-day-of-year-to-date))

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method that you can use is to get the year's data with partial string indexing, then `resample` annually

```
df1['1990-12-31':].resample('A', how='first')
```

The string slicing is described in the pandas documentation under 17.4.1 DatetimeIndex Partial String Indexing.  With this method, you can cut out the creation of the timedelta, the second date_range, and the complex and erroneous slicing.  The resample method is standard, using 'A' as a signifier for "annual" frequency and how='first' to just grab the first matching item.

```
            0
1990-12-31 -0.600904
1991-12-31 -1.083462
1992-12-31  0.469949
1993-12-31 -0.809852
1994-12-31 -0.165877
1995-12-31  1.460035
1996-12-31 -0.332960
1997-12-31 -0.140873
1998-12-31  1.088687
1999-12-31  0.190218
```

[Check out the pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/pandas.pdf), look into 17.4.1 DatetimeIndex Partial String Indexing
[Here is the TimeSeries documentation mentioning resampling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html)
And finally, [the API doc for the `resample()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample) method

Comment: Ah, doesn't answer what OP has asked for.

Comment: It surely does @John Galt
(1) there is a better way to extract yearly data for a particular date ? Yes, with partal string indexing, described above and 
(2) the time series in the dataframe and date_range list are different. I would appreciate information on both problems.  My method avoids both problems

Comment: May be you're right, I'll leave it to OP =) on a side note, year index is a good find, I didn't know about it's existence, Thanks.

Comment: I updated with evidence to show that the index is properly sliced with partial string indexing, hopefully that'll make the case more clearly

Comment: I'm not sure if my post was clear. I am trying to get data out of the DataFrame at an annual level on a particular date.  I do not want the entire year's data.  I want data for a particular day of the year, every year.

Comment: I did not understand that, I'll need to rework it.  Hold tight