# Import everyday date for one year

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlite, calendar

Is there a simple way to import into my Python file a list with all the dates for a given year?
What I need is to store everyday that a year has (01.01.2018----31.12.2018) into a list, so I can then import this list into a column in a table in a SQL database.

I have been Google for hours and didn´t find anything but there should be a way to import this directly...

Anyone knows? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it's completely possible. It's also possible to make the date range without any external file other than importing standard modules. There's not enough info here to correct your approach

Comment: Use the `datetime` package and a simple loop to generate the dates: start on 01 Jan and keep adding a day.  Convert each date to the day format you want.  Concatenate these into a list.  Once you understand the `datetime` functions well, you can even do that in a list comprehension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through a range of dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

This seems a bit cleaner for what he's looking for and it's a one-liner!

```
import datetime

year = 2018
datelist = [d for d in range(datetime.date(year,12,31)-datetime.date(year,1,1)).days)]
```

This will result in `datelist` being a `list` from `[1, 2, 3, ... 365/366]`.

**Edit** Added Patrick's suggestion and correct formatting as required

All you will need to do to get the format you want would be to get the date from the number explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427555/python-question-year-and-day-of-year-to-date) and format it correctly. which can also be done in one line but it's a little much for some.

```
datelist = [datetime.fromordinal(date(year, 1, 1).toordinal() + d - 1).strftime("dd.mm.yyyy") for d in range(1,365+ 1 if isLeap(year) else 0))]
```

Broken down, here's the long way of the above:

```
datelist = []
for d in range(1,365+ 1 if isLeap(year) else 0):
    day = datetime.fromordinal(date(year, 1, 1).toordinal() + d - 1)
    datelist.append(day.strftime("dd.mm.yyyy"))
```

This results in a list looking like:

```
["01.01.2018", "02.01.2018", ... "31.12.2018"]
```

Answer (score 2):

With Sqlite, you can do this directly in SQL, no python needed, thanks to recursive CTEs:

```sql
CREATE TABLE days(day TEXT PRIMARY KEY) WITHOUT ROWID;
INSERT INTO days(day)
  WITH RECURSIVE alldays(day) AS
       (VALUES ('2018-01-01')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT date(day, '+1 day')
        FROM alldays
        LIMIT 366 -- Take leap years into account
       )
  SELECT day FROM alldays WHERE day <= '2018-12-31';
-- List days in October:
SELECT day FROM days WHERE day BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-31' ORDER BY day;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can start with a datetime of `2018-1-1` and add a range of `0` to `364/365` days to that:

```
import datetime

def getDays(year):
    """Generates all days in one year, respecting leap years. Uses Gregorian
    calendarso best keep the year post 1582."""
    def isLeap(y):
        return y%4 == 0 and ( not y % 100 == 0 or y % 400 == 0)

    dt = datetime.date(year,1,1)
    days = 365 + (1 if isLeap(dt.year) else 0) # needs the (..) due to operator precedence

    return (dt + datetime.timedelta(days=k) for k in range( days ) ) 

print(list(getDays(2018)))
```

Output:

```
[datetime.date(2018, 1, 1), datetime.date(2018, 1, 2), datetime.date(2018, 1, 3), ..., 
 datetime.date(2018, 12, 29), datetime.date(2018, 12, 30), datetime.date(2018, 12, 31)]
```

---

Leapyears:

```
for y in [1900,2000]:
    d = list(getDays(y))
    print(d[58:60], d[-1:])
```

Ouput:

```
# 1900 - not a leap yeaer
[datetime.date(1900, 2, 28), datetime.date(1900, 3, 1)] [datetime.date(1900, 12, 31)]

# 2000 - a leap year
[datetime.date(2000, 2, 28), datetime.date(2000, 2, 29)] [datetime.date(2000, 12, 31)]
```

Comment: Would fail on a leap year, no?

Comment: It's not my downvote, should be relatively easy to fix, but it's fallible I'm sure.

Comment: @roganjosh already fixed. the OP explicitly asked for 2018 -and we do not have a leapday in 2018 ...

Answer (score -1):

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

#get starting date 01.01.2018
startingDate = date(date.today().year, 1, 1)
currentDate = startingDate
for _ in range(365):
    print(currentDate.strftime('%m.%d.%Y'))
    #get next day
    currentDate = currentDate + timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Since your date format is dd-mm-yy,  
use this instead:
print(currentDate.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'))

Comment: Thanks a lot! This one made it for my case