# How to insert one full year range of dates into SQLite table column

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, date

So I have an empty table in a database in SQLite, just with one column (DATES).

Any idea how to automatically update this column with dates from 2019/01/01 to 2019/12/31?

I would like to know if there is any specific code in SQL for such a simple thing that in spreadsheet would be just drag down.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I put this up a few days ago as an answer to another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53054594/9952196

Comment: Thanks I just saw your answer. I was just wondering if there is a more straight way to do it, since it seems quite few lines of code for such a standard and simple thing

Comment: It's only a few lines, and not something I've seen done very often. Writing SQL is just like programming... You have to build what you need out of smaller parts, there's not a magic "do what I want" wand that solves all problems with a single function.

Comment: Look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69497590/111036). It has a command to populate a "days" table in your wanted range, which you can then use easily in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend updating the existing table.  Just create a new one:

```
create table dates as
with cte as (
      select date('2019-01-01') as dte union all
      select date(dte, '+1 day')
      from cte
      where dte < '2020-12-31'
     )
select *
from cte;
```

If this is for occasional use, you can just use the CTE rather than storing the results in a table.