# Converting a string that has day of the year to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a string column that looks like below:

```
2018-24 7:10:0      
2018-8 12:1:20      
2018-44 13:55:19
```

The 24,8,44 that you see are the day of the year and not the date.
How can I convert this to datetime column in the below format ?

```
2018-01-24 07:10:00
2018-01-08 12:01:20
2018-02-13 13:55:19
```

I am unable to find anything related to converting day of the year ?

Comment: When you say column, is this a pandas dataframe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427555/python-question-year-and-day-of-year-to-date

Comment: Yes it’s pandas dataframe

Comment: I've added pandas specific method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need format string `'%Y-%j %H:%M:%S'`

```
In[53]:
import datetime as dt
dt.datetime.strptime('2018-44 13:55:19', '%Y-%j %H:%M:%S')

Out[53]: datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 13, 13, 55, 19)
```

[`%j`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) is day of year

For `pandas`:

```
In[59]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""2018-24 7:10:0
2018-8 12:1:20
2018-44 13:55:19"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=None, names=['datetime'])
df

Out[59]: 
           datetime
0    2018-24 7:10:0
1    2018-8 12:1:20
2  2018-44 13:55:19
```

Use [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) and pass `format` param:

```
In[60]:
df['new_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%Y-%j %H:%M:%S')
df

Out[60]: 
           datetime        new_datetime
0    2018-24 7:10:0 2018-01-24 07:10:00
1    2018-8 12:1:20 2018-01-08 12:01:20
2  2018-44 13:55:19 2018-02-13 13:55:19
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dateutil.relativedelta for sum the day from the first day of years.

example:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

datetime.now()+ relativedelta(days=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation at strftime.org](http://strftime.org/) identifies the `%j` format specifier as handling day of the year. I don't know whether it's available on all platforms, but my Mac certainly has it.

Use `time.strptime` to convert from string to datetime. The output below has a newline inserted for reading convenience:

```
>>> time.strptime('2018-24 7:10:0', '%Y-%j %H:%M:%S')
time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=24, tm_hour=7,
       tm_min=10, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=24, tm_isdst=-1)
```

The `time.strftime` formats datetimes, so you can get what you need by applying it to the output of `strptime`:

```
>>> time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
...               time.strptime('2018-24 7:10:0', '%Y-%j %H:%M:%S'))
'2018-01-24 07:10:00'
```