# Day number to Date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the day of the year (e.g. 295). I want to convert that to it's equivalent, October 22.
I have this for multiple years so each time the routine should update the year once it reaches 365 or 366.
Is there any built in function for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Question: Year and Day of Year to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427555/python-question-year-and-day-of-year-to-date)

Comment: @blacksite It does for the first part. Any idea how to update the years?

Comment: It should be automatic `pd.to_datetime('2000-01-01') + df.to_timedelta(df['day'], unit='D')`, remember to replace `2000-01-01` with your start year.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for your help but the year is still not updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you mentioned in the comment that the year is not updating:

```
s = pd.Series([1,20,56,290,356,3,5,7,100])
start_year = 2000

# calculate the years
years = s.diff().lt(0).cumsum()+start_year

# final output
pd.to_datetime(years, format='%Y') + pd.to_timedelta(s-1, unit='D')
```

Output:

```
0   2000-01-01
1   2000-01-20
2   2000-02-25
3   2000-10-16
4   2000-12-21
5   2001-01-03
6   2001-01-05
7   2001-01-07
8   2001-04-10
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: My data-frame column is like [1,20,56,290,356,3,5,7,100]

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you are looking for:

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019 110', '%Y %j')
x.strftime('%B %d')

'April 30'
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is for a single year. I have a data-frame column with days from multiple years placed sequentially. So I am looking for something to upgrade the year once it reaches 365/366

Comment: You can't apply it to all the column ? You can use the lambda function for that