# Convert Day of Year integer to Day and Month integers in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, attributeerror

I have an integer representing the day of the year from 1-365 in my array `out` at index 0. How do i convert this to get the month and day of month from this using Python and Pandas?

I have tried:

```
out[0] = pd.to_datetime(out[0]).dt.strftime('%m-%d')
```

but I get an error saying `AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'`

Comment: so what's the year? think leap years...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Question: Year and Day of Year to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427555/python-question-year-and-day-of-year-to-date)

Comment: You have to add an starting year/date and delete the .dt for your timestamp. My solution would be this ```pd.to_datetime(out[0]-1 ,unit='D',origin=pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01')).strftime('%m-%d')```

Comment: cheers @campy your solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You have to know if it's a leap year or not?
If it's a leap year, February has 29 days, if not 28.
Otherwise your conversion will not be correct.

> Leap Years are any year that can be exactly divided by 4 (such as 2016, 2020, 2024, etc) except if it can be exactly divided by 100, then it isn't (such as 2100, 2200, etc) except if it can be exactly divided by 400, then it is (such as 2000, 2400)