# Get Month and Day of the month from Day of the year

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

I have those data'.
Year, Day of the year and it's a Leap year

Need to print "Month, Day" from given data.

```
year= 2020
day_oy= 357
```

I tried,

```
if day_ in range(1,32):
    new_month= "January"
elif day_ in range(32, 61):
    new_month= "February"

...

else:
    new_month= "December"
```

and it takes many lines. And I need to do it using minimum lines.

Comment: What is your expected result ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

day_of_the_year = 357
year = 2020

datetime_object = datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(day_of_the_year - 1)

# get month and day of the month

month = datetime_object.month
day_of_the_month = datetime_object.day

print(f"{day_of_the_month}/{month}")
```

Output:

```
22/12
```

Once you get the `datetime object`, you can get any details of the date in any format.

Refer to the below documentation for further details.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427581) you probably want:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

year = 2020
day_oy = 357

date = datetime(year=year, month=1, day=1)
date_oy = date + timedelta(days=day_oy - 1)
new_month = date_oy.strftime('%B')  # December
```